# Драйвер клавиатуры

Tags: c

Как работать с драйвером клавиатуры? Язык C. (У меня ноутбук, клавиатура встроена в корпус, вероятно, она по-другому подключена (не по USB), не знаю, но предупреждаю заранее) ОС Ubuntu.
Конечная цель - написать демона, который издает вопль при нажатии на клавишу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого вам не нужен никакой драйвер. Судя по Ubuntu в вопросе, всё нужное можно найти в области `<X11/Xlib.h>` и `<X11/Xutil.h>`. Вот простенький пример.  Сборка:

```
gcc test.c -lX11
```

Запускать в терминале. Перехватываем нажатие только определённых клавиш (где угодно, хоть в любом другом окне), выходим по клавише `q`:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static int grabKey( Display *display, Window window, KeyCode keycode )
{
    // без модификаторов:
    unsigned int modifiers = 0;
    Bool ownerEvents  = 1;
    int  pointerMode  = GrabModeAsync;
    int  keyboardMode = GrabModeAsync;

    XGrabKey( display, keycode, modifiers, window, ownerEvents, pointerMode,
              keyboardMode );
    return keycode;
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static void ungrabKey( Display *display, Window window, KeyCode keycode )
{
    unsigned int modifiers = 0; 
    XUngrabKey( display, keycode, modifiers, window );
}

/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main( void )
{
    XEvent   event;
    Display *display = XOpenDisplay( 0 );
    Window   root    = DefaultRootWindow( display );

    KeyCode A = XKeysymToKeycode( display, 'a' );
    KeyCode B = XKeysymToKeycode( display, 'b' );
    KeyCode C = XKeysymToKeycode( display, 'c' );
    KeyCode Q = XKeysymToKeycode( display, 'q' );

    grabKey( display, root, A );
    grabKey( display, root, B );
    grabKey( display, root, C );
    grabKey( display, root, Q );

    XSelectInput( display, root, KeyPressMask );

    do {
        XNextEvent( display, &event );

        if( event.type == KeyPress ) {
            printf( "key pressed: %d\n", event.xkey.keycode );
        }
    } while( event.type != KeyPress || event.xkey.keycode != Q );

    ungrabKey( display, root, Q );
    ungrabKey( display, root, C );
    ungrabKey( display, root, B );
    ungrabKey( display, root, A );
    XCloseDisplay( display );

    return 0;
}
/* -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  That'a All, Folks!
 * ---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

---

И [пример посложней, с обработкой всяких разных событий](http://webhamster.ru/site/page/index/articles/comp/367) (проверил на Mint - собирается и работает).

Comment: 1. Компилировать надо так: `gcc q.c -lstdc++ -lX11 -lXext -lXi`? 2. У меня в linux mint 17.3 не работает. Почему?

Comment: @Qwertiy, мой пример: `gcc test.c  -lX11`, который по ссылке: `g++ test.cpp -lX11 -lXext -lXi` (не забыть пописать правильный ID клавиатуры в `sprintf(deviceId, "12");`, брать из `xinput`). Тоже Mint 17.3, всё собирается и работает.

Comment: Что надо сделать, чтобы твой пример заработал? У меня он не работает? Где в нём id клавиатуры и как мне его получить?

Comment: @Qwertiy, id клавиатуры нужен только для второго, по ссылке всё подробно описано. Первый собирается `gcc test.c -lX11` и работает без дополнительных условий. Как и второй. По крайней мере у меня на минт 17.3 :) Проверю чуть позже на каком-нибудь другом дистрибутиве.

Comment: У меня Mint 17.3 и не работает. Компилируется, запускается, ничего не выводит. Закрывается только нажатием Ctrl+C. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: @Qwertiy, http://xxo.su/resizer/i/5/b/a3f81de8.png Учёл, что перехватываются только 4 клавиши? `abcq`. На другие реакции быть и не должно.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47840/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-pinktux).