# Обработка событий клавиатуры в DOS

Tags: c, клавиатура, dos

Мне нужно создать окно, размеры которого можно менять нажатием клавиши.

К примеру Right Shift в программе Borland C++ 3.1 на языке программирования Си. Само окно я создал, но не понимаю, как написать функцию, которая бы понимала, что нажата нужная клавиша и меняла бы размер окна. Прошу вас о помощи.

Comment: Как минимум, для начала почитайте про [listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220818/detect-keyboard-event-in-c).

Comment: Хотя бы ОС укажите. Раз BC 3.1 - DOS? Тогда идеальный (но суровый) вариант - свой обработчик `int 9` :)

Comment: @Dave Manston  Вам наверное проще будет использовать классы Turbo Vision, в которых эта операция уже заложена.

Comment: @PinkTux Windows 7, но работаю в Борланде через DosBox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Неправильный путь - опрашивать устройства ввода внутри элемента, который получил фокус. Его даже рассматривать не будем, сразу перейдём к правильному.

Правильный - внешний обработчик, который ставит полученные события в очередь. И эта очередь доступна окнам, кнопкам и прочим объектам.

В Windows тут специально ничего делать не надо, эта схема обработки событий и так присутствует изначально.

Для DOS идеальным решением будет работа с прерываниями (свой обработчик `int 9h` для клавиатуры, `int 33h` для мыши и т.д.). Именно так устроена обработка событий в Turbo Vision, поэтому имеет смысл не изобретать велосипед, а взять всё оттуда. Тем более что исходники есть.

Для Linux всё немного сложней (см. [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585554/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B#585611), и это не единственный вариант), но общий смысл остаётся тот же.

И главное, что нужно понять. Несмотря на то, что общий принцип один и тот же, реализация его очень сильно завязана на ОС и платформу, и именно она составляет львиную долю работы (*ни язык C, ни язык C++ не имеют средств для полноценной работы с устройствами ввода, поэтому всё нужно делать самостоятельно*). И тратя время на DOS нужно хорошо понмать зачем это делается, так как в подавляющем большинстве случаев время это будет потрачено впустую.

Comment: , спасибо за совет, а нет ли у вас примера использования TurboVision, ибо я только на теорию натыкаюсь

Comment: @DaveManston, все примеры TurboVision в его исходниках. Сам я эту окаменелость почти  20 лет назад последний раз видел, так что не подскажу точней.

Comment: понял, и на этом спасибо)