# C++. Keyboard Input. Отлов нажатия

Tags: c++, linux, input

Всем доброго времени суток.
Возможно, дубликат, но пока действенной инфы(кроме либы SDL и std::cin) не увидел. SFML(использующийся для рендера) как и std::cin блокируются зажатием клавиши.
Linux. C++ 17.
Какие есть способы отлавливать нажатия на кнопки клавиатуры?
К примеру, необходимо задетектить KeyDown клавиши, передать её по событию и ждать  KeyUp(события реализованы, вопрос только в инпуте НЕ через Win).

Comment: Или, к примеру, сделать запрос к кому-нибудь(ось\прочее) типа bool\KeyStateStruct GetKeyState(SomeKeyEnum.BACKSPACE);
Получая соответственно некоторое значение, указывающее на состояние клавиши.

Comment: Начните [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/415922/194908)

Comment: А отлов нажатия в собственной программе или глобально? на уровне системы? Если на уровне системы, то надо хук вешать, удобнее всего в формате драйвера.

Comment: Выкладывал кому-то, посмотрите, может чего пригодиться, неполные исходники драйвера Клавы на *nix, смотреть в основном на [asm исходники](https://gist.github.com/ClnViewer/0577a6b32eb277657ef9ee0b53dfc75e), остальное для ориентации как оно вызывается.

Comment: есть три основных источника подобных событий: низкоуровневый интерфейс ядра (evdev), терминал (с надстройками вроде curses) и API X-сервера (X11 или другого графического менеджера). Какой именно из них использовать зависит от того какого рода приложение ты собираешься делать. Для каждого из них есть свои настройки/библиотеки, а также свои варианты.

Comment: Во, [кстати](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/585554/%D0%94%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D1%8B/585611#585611). Пример для X.

Comment: Если Вы используете SFML, то неужели же в модуле Window нет ничего вроде onKeyPressed()?!